# Power series $ f(g(z)) = z $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f(z) = z + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nz^n $ have a positive radius of convergence. Does there exist a series $ g(z) = z + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}b_nz^n $, satisfying
\begin{equation}
f(g(z))=z?
\end{equation}
Does this series have a positive radius of convergence? Are the coefficients $ \{b_n\} $ uniquely determined?

Comment: [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes, and yes.

$f$ is bijective in a neighbourhood of $0$ - since $f'(0) = 1 \neq 0$ - hence the inverse exists in a neighbourhood of $0$. The inverse is holomorphic too, hence has a power series expansion, and that starts with $0 + 1\cdot z$ since $g(0) = f^{-1}(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = \frac{1}{f'(0)} = 1$. Power series expansions are always uniquely determined as witnessed by the identity theorem.