# To solve the radius of convergence of a power series in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^n$ have a positive radius of convergence. Does there exist a series $g(z)=z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_nz^n$, satisfying
>   $$
> f(g(z))=z\text{?}\tag{49}
> $$
>   Does this series have a positive radius of convergence? Are the coefficients $\left\{b_n\right\}$ uniquely determined?

I don't think completely expand all the terms of f (g(z)) is a good idea, can you give me some other methods to solve it? Thank you so much.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgesh.png).

Comment: You can use the implicit function theorem for holomorphic functions, for example.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465423/power-series-fgz-z?rq=1